# Getting back a blank Wordpress site following functions code edit

Tags: functions, themes, child-theme

I added some function code to the functions.php file of my child theme that has now set my entire site blank.

Is the only way to get it back via cPanel and changing the theme back to the parent them in PHPMyAdmin under wp-options? (The entire is site is blank on both frontend and admin)

Answer (score 0):

Either Phpmyadmin or using FTP to edit the functions.php. As you have cpanel there is live FTP that works directly from browser

Answer (score 0):

Another option here is to enable WP_DEBUG in your wp-config.php file in the root folder. It may provide you with some more information on what's causing the issue. More information on that here: https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG